# Meaning of a simple pattern of preg_replace (#\s+#)?

Tags: php

Sorry for the very basic question, but *there's simply no easy way to search for a string like that* [nor here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters) neither in Google or [SymbolHound](http://www.symbolhound.com/). Also haven't found an answer in PHP Manual ([Pattern Syntax](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) & [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)).

This code is inside a function that receives the `$content` and `$length` parameters.
What does that `preg_replace` serves for?

```
$the_string = preg_replace('#\s+#', ' ', $content);
$words = explode(' ', $the_string);

if( count($words) <= $length )
```

Also, would it be better to use [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) instead?

Comment: space (`\s`) more than one time (`+`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This pattern replaces successive space characters (note, not just spaces, but also line breaks or tabs) with a single, conventional space (' '). `\s+` says "match a sequence, made up of one or more space characters".

The `#` signs are delimiters for the pattern. Probably more common is to see patterns delimited by forward slashes. (Actually you can do REGEX in PHP without delimiters but doing so has implications on how the pattern is handled, which is beyond the scope of this question/answer).

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Relying on spaces to find words in a string is generally not the best approach - we can use the `\b` word boundary marker instead.

```
$sentence = "Hello, there. How are you today? Hope you're OK!";
preg_match_all('/\b[\w-]+\b/', $sentence, $words);
```

That says: grab all substrings within the greater string that are comprised of only alphanumeric characters or hyphens, and which are encased by a word boundary.

`$words` is now an array of words used in the sentence.

Comment: The *line breaks or tabs* seems a detail of great relevance. Thx for that!

Comment: Oh, yes, I suppose the `preg_match_all` will handle the line breaks and tabs as well, right?

Comment: Thanks @Pete. brasofilo - yes, the `\s` shortcut matches any spacial character. Line-breaks are allowed. (A common misconception is that you have to turn on multi-line mode for this to happen - in fact, multi-line mode has a completely different concern. I did a [blog on this here](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2011/Jun/Understanding-multi-line-mode-for-JS-REGEX-179)).

Answer (score 1):

`\s+` is used to match multiple spaces.
You are replacing them with a single space, using `preg_replace('#\s+#', ' ', $content);`

`str_word_count` might be suitable, but you might need to specify additional characters which count as words, or the function reports wrong values when using UTF-8 characters.

```
str_word_count($str, 1, characters_that_are_not_considered_word_boundaries);
```

**EXAMPLE**:

```
print_r(str_word_count('holóeóó what',1));
```

returns

```
Array ( [0] => hol [1] => e [2] => what )
```

Comment: What do the # symbols do? Are they like / ? EDIT: answered above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`#` is [delimiter](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and
>   tildes (~). The following are all examples of valid delimited
>   patterns.

```
$the_string = preg_replace('#\s+#', ' ', $content);
```

it will replace multiple space (`\s`) with single space